# Bruno: Is there a way to escape variable substitution in Bruno?

Tags: bruno

Is there currently a way to escape variable substitution in Bruno? In our use case, we have a query body that contains something like `"{{VALUE_THAT_IS_NOT_RELEVANT_FOR_BRUNO}}"`

When we run that query, Bruno interprets it as a variable that needs substituting, but because no environment variable exists with that name, Bruno substitutes a blank value. In our case, we would want to escape the variable substitution characters `"{{"` without that escape character (whatever it may be) showing up in the subsequent query request body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a `\` before the variable should do the trick

[image]

Bruno uses the [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com) templating engine for variable replacement. I think this is the section [in the docs](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#escaping-handlebars-expressions).